# Console input java. Parsing a string

Tags: java, console

I have a console application where I need to input numbers until enter "x".
Of course when I input "x" i will get a NumberFormatException.

How would I quit the program when entering "x" without getting an exception.

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    int input;
    String name = args[0];
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();


    System.out.println("Good morning " + name + " Today's date is " + sdf.format(date));

    System.out.println("Please enter any number between 0 and 10");

    try
    {


        do
        {
        s = buf.readLine();

        input = Integer.parseInt(s);

        while(input <= 0 || input > 10)
        {
            System.out.println("Make sure about the correct input...between 0 and 10 please");
            s = buf.readLine();
            input = Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        }while(s != "x");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a line

```
s = buf.readLine();
if ("x".equals(s)) break; // add this line
```

This does not guarantee that `s` is an integer, so you still need to catch an exception like andreas proposed

Answer (score 3):

Reorder the loop(s) to check if `s` is equal to `x` before `Integer.parseInt()`. Use `String.equals()` to compare strings, not `==` or `!=`.

*As this is homework I will not post modified code.*

EDIT:

Just to explain the reason for using `String.equals()`:

From section *15.21.3 Reference Equality Operators == and !=* of the *Java Language Specification 3.0*:

> While == may be used to compare references of type String, such an equality test determines whether or not the two operands refer to the same String object. The result is false if the operands are distinct String objects, even if they contain the same sequence of characters. The contents of two strings s and t can be tested for equality by the method invocation s.equals(t).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the code in try..catch block.

```
input=-1;
try{
  input = Integer.parseInt(s);
  while(input <= 0 || input > 10)
  {
   System.out.println("Make sure about the correct input...between 0 and 10 please");
   s = buf.readLine();
   input = Integer.parseInt(s);
   System.out.println(input);
   }
}catch(Exception ex) { }
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `Integer.parseInt` statement in a try/catch block:

```
try {
 input = Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch{NumberFormatException nfe) {
 System.out.println("Illegal input");
 // know you could do one of the following: (uncomment)
 // continue;        // would continue the while loop
 // break;           // would exit the while loop
 // System.exit(0);  // would exit the application
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to a while loop and do

```
while (s != "x") {
  // your logic
```

}

or check if s != "x" before this line:

```
input = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the exception:

```
s = buf.readLine();
if("x".compareToIgnoreCase(s)) {
  // im quit
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a if statement before paring the string to a int:

```
    if(s.equals("x"))
       system.exit(1);

    else{
    input = Integer.parseInt(s);

            while(input <= 0 || input > 10)
            {
                System.out.println("Make sure about the correct input...between 0 and 10 please");
                s = buf.readLine();
                input = Integer.parseInt(s);
                System.out.println(input);
}
```